# .Each will lag the website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to manupulate the DOM, but code I am using is slowing down the website. I think `.each` is slowing it down as it has to go through all the divs and make the changes over and over. Here is my code:

```
var emojirun = function() {
    $('.message').each(function(i, d) {
        $(d).emoji();
    });
};
```

Is there a way to make this faster? Thank you for your help!

I am trying to use this jquery emoji
https://github.com/linyows/jquery-emoji

Comment: Really depends on the machine, but normally a loop is not felt unless it's doing some major calculations. What is this `emoji` function? And also, how many `.message`'s are there?

Comment: What's action is performed by `emoji`?

Comment: @fingeron  I am using this to add emoji on a chat, everytime a new message is added this function needs to read if it has any emojis like :happy: and change it with the png file of an actual emoji. To run the function again, I am using setInterval.

Comment: It'll be a lot better to apply the `emoji()` function to a `.message` every times it is created. Can you show us the function that creates the message?

Comment: Hi @Santosh, maybe you want to re thinking or your team needs handle the message data in different way so that it displays the icons out of the box. have a look at this article its by Mathias who worked at google explains how to store and display emojis directly on your browser. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4, so you don't need any editional javascript to output emojis. of course it all depends if you have your own emojis ignore my comment.

Comment: @fingeron I am trying to use this jquery emoji https://github.com/linyows/jquery-emoji